# using winform to pass installation path from winform to custom action

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

i am trying to create custom windows installer using windows forms. 
how to create custom action which can accept installation path from windows form for installation. 
i am trying to assign value from windows form to `this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]` but the application is installing at default path i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Setup1`.

```
public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Install(savedState);
            const string key_path = "SOFTWARE\\VendorName\\MyAppName";
            const string key_value_name = "InstallationDirectory";

            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

            if (key == null)
            {
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(key_path);
            }
            this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"] = default_installation_path;
            string tgt_dir = this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"];
            key.SetValue(key_value_name, tgt_dir);
        }
```

please help me i am new to installer class.

Comment: What installer are you using?  There are many on the market.  If you are using the Visual Studio Setup Project, I suggest using a different tool, they discontinued it in Visual Studio 2012 for a reason ( it was horrible to work with ).  Why are you trying to NOT install your application in the CORRECT location?

Comment: thanx. can u suggest which installer is easy or more customizable.